What is the Integer after a multiplication within a SQL query?
I try to insert data into a database.
This is my code:
b = request.form.get("b")
d = int(request.form.get("c"))
f = db.execute("SELECT DISTINCT column1 *:multiplier FROM table1 WHERE type=:c", c=b, multiplier=d)
db.execute(INSERT INTO table2 (column1,column2) VALUES (?,?),session["user_id"],f)

I get this error:

raise runtimeerror("unsupported value: {}".format
runtimeError: unsupported value :{"column1 *1" :150}

I do not know what I am doing wrong. The tables are set on integer.
Could someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

You MAY just need a space between the * and the :multiplier.
However, you're also missing quotes around your INSERT statement.
